# Override Library and File names in Craslytics Non-fatal error reports

Tags: ios, firebase, logging, crashlytics

We're using Crashlytics in our app for crash reporting and general logging tool.

Naturally, to avoid importing Firebase into every part of our app, we wrap the logging functionality in a `Logger` interface, and inject Firebase at the top level.

```
public protocol Logger {
    func log(error: Error)
}

final class LoggerImpl: Logger {
    func log(error: Error) {
        Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
    }
}
```

Frustratingly, this means every non-fatal we log implicates the top-level app module, and the LoggerImpl file.

[image: LoggerImpl implicated in every non-fatal]

We need to drill down into the error's stack trace (Crashlytics uses `NSThread callStackReturnAddresses` internally) to find the culprit.

[image: Stack trace drill-down to find the real error]

Is there any way to override behaviour on Crashlytics so this extremely common dependency-injection pattern can work better?

Looking through the Crashlytics API itself, the only method which seems plausible is `recordError(error: userInfo:)`, however I was unable to find any documentation or work out any combination of keys and values which overrode the basic library/file in the UI.

If anyone has any thoughts, please let me know! I've also created a feature request in the [Firebase Github page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/12462).

Comment: I’m confused. I am using it for extensive logging - I set the error domain to come unique value in each usage (com.<app>.<where>). You can use iOS to generate a stack trace too - but unique domain means you know where it comes from. You can create a new error, include the original in it.